# Duplicated question with another solution

Tags: support, duplicate-question

There are some questions from other years that now have a new answer or solution.
As this case:

[How to force paths instead polygons when exporting images as svg?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/116466/120647)

What to do?

- Flag it as a duplicate (without adding any new solution)
- Flag it as a duplicate and answer with a new solution
- Answer with the duplicate link and the new solution

BTW: the link of the original question doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Actually there are more than 2

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but I believe I saw a post somewhere that said you merge the new answer into the old question, and close the new question. Assuming the answer is actually decent, and assuming the original question has some decent answers too. Otherwise, close either as a dupe. Only mods can do that though. Think I saw a post like that on some meta somewhere in the network (I don't really remember), so like I said, don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 3):

Add a new answer to the old question and mark the new one as duplicate. This way there's only one question asked, with updated answers. If the OP is still around and we're lucky to grab their attention they change the accepted answer.

Comment: Exactly what I would recommend.